Handlebar expression to return object from JSON string/array
I have a SharePoint multiple lines of text column that is being populated with a JSON string from a SQL table.
I don't have access to the SQL table, so am trying to manually manipulate the data within a template file.
I am trying to display the data in PnP Search v4 using a custom html/handlebar expression template.
But beyond displaying a simple one line of data, I am a bit out of my depth.
My data:
 [{"OwnerNumber": 5463, "OwnerName": "John Doe" },{"OwnerNumber": 5466, "OwnerName": "Jane Doe"}]
My very simple template:
`
<content>
  <div class="myOwnerTemplate">
    <ul class="ms-OwnerList" style="font-family:'Arial'; padding-inline-start:0px;">
      <ownertable>  
        <tr>
          <th>Owner # &emsp;&emsp;</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          {{#each data.items as |item|}}<td>{{RefinableString109}}</td>{{/each}}
        </tr>
      </ownertable>
    </ul>
  </div>
</content>

EDIT:
The SharePoint column where the data is pulled from is a Multiple Line of Text column. I have mapped this to a managed property; Refinablestring109.
Hence the template calls Refinablestring109 and displays that data to the SharePoint app/page.
enter image description here
How it appears now:
enter image description here
How I want it to appear:
enter image description here
Any help at all would be very appreciated, please?

I don't know what to make of this. I see nothing called RefinableString109 in your data, but you are referencing it in your template.

Sorry. The SharePoint column is a multiple line of text column. I have mapped this to Refinablestring109. So in my template, it is calling Refinablestring109, and that is what is displaying the data on the page.
